Can I use "Get Records" and "contains" with multi-picklist values in a flow?
I've designed a screen flow where the end user can select multiple values from a picklist. Consequently, I have created a Picklist choice set to capture this data and utilize the selected values to retrieve all corresponding records.
For instance, one of the fields is "Country" with a picklist datatype. Let's say the user opts for two countries, such as USA and Canada. I am getting these two values in a picklist choice set resource. Then, I'm employing this choice set within the "Get Records" element, utilizing the "contains" condition against the actual field.
During debugging, when a single country is selected, all records are successfully retrieved. However, if two countries are selected, the flow fails to locate records.
What could be the oversight here? Would employing a collection variable and iterating through them be necessary? There are a total of 10 fields similar to this one that need to be integrated into the flow. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

From my experience you will have to add the choices into a collection variable in order to utilize the "contains" operator in a "Get Records" element.
I had input in the form of ["Choice 1"; "Choice 2";] where I had to strip the square brackets first and then add each choice into a text collection variable. It was quite painful, but I got the end result.
You might be able to use a bunch of decision elements to check what was selected and then add the value to the text collection variable, but that in a sense is "hard coding" and is not scalable.
You can also use Apex in an Invocable Action to create the collection variable for you.
Multi-select picklists are great for capturing data in screen flows, but can be really painful when used in a data extraction process and that is why I use them with caution.
Good luck!
